# How do I get the returnvalue from my controller in my lightning controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller

How do I get the value of my controller in my lighning controller

I have the following ligntningcomponent:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="NavigateToProfielController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.openPage}"/>
</aura:component>
```

With The following Controller:

```
({
    openPage: function (component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.LoggedInUserContact");
        var url = '/flow/LerarenCommunity_Licentie_Verlenging?varProfielId="' + recordId +'"';
        window.open(url, '_self');
    }
})
```

In my NavigateToProfielController I need to call LoggedInUserContact from which I want to pass the value to the RecordId

My URL output gives me undefined:

```
https:.../flow/LerarenCommunity_Licentie_Verlenging?varProfielId="undefined"
```

Comment: You should really start by learning [basic lightning components developements](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics).

Comment: @Martin I tried that but apparently I dint understood quite well. So I would be nice to give a helping answer, but tanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a typo in my code because of using c.openPage I had to use c.getLoggedInUser instead of **v**.LoggedInUserContact and had to use **get**